# Undefined reference to an Oracle Call Interface Function Call

Tags: c, oracle-call-interface

I have an OCI application intended to use the OCI function calls and specifically for multi-threading. Other function calls works fine but some are not working properly.

I tried checking if they are included in the `oci.h`, calling them in a different code and ensuring that the OCI had been added as a header file and on path but the `oci_threaded` functions are not working yet.

Here is part of the error:

````
/usr/bin/ld: Sample.o: in function `main':
Sample.c:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `OCIConnectionPoolCreate
/usr/bin/ld: Sample.c:(.text+0x1b4): undefined reference to `OCIThreadProcessInit
/usr/bin/ld: Sample.c:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `OCIThreadInit
/usr/bin/ld: Sample.c:(.text+0x21e): undefined reference to `OCIThreadIdInit
/usr/bin/ld: Sample.c:(.text+0x260): undefined reference to `OCIThreadHndInit
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:17: oci_test] Error 1```
````

Comment: What kind of error do you have? at building (compilation / link), at runtime?
Could you post a [MCVE]

Comment: At building @Mathieu. I have added the output.

Comment: and how do you build?

Comment: I have a Makefile alongside, so I run `make`.

Comment: ... and what is the command called by `make` that generate the error, you can try with `make -n`

Comment: Running `make -n` generate `gcc` command on the terminal.

Comment: Which is? My first question was about that very command: how is `gcc` called? what are its parameters?...

Comment: That points to that you need to include some other Oracle library you have not included.